# Python CSV seek not working?

Tags: python, csv, seek

```
 file_handle = open("/var/www/transactions.csv", "a")
  c = csv.writer(file_handle);

 oldamount = amount / 1.98
  file_handle.seek(0);

  c.writerow( [addre, oldamount, "win"])
```

Here is my code

I wish to write [addre, oldamount, "win"]) to the start of my CSV file, however it's not working. It's still going to the bottom.

Answer (score 3):

You are opening the file in append (`"a"`) mode. The [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/functions.html#open) for `open()` points out this behavior explicitly: "all writes append to the end of the file regardless of the current seek position".

It isn't possible to "just insert" text at the beginning of a file like you want to. You can either read the whole file, add your data in the front, and write it back out, or you live with the fact that the data goes at the end.

Example for rewriting:

```
with open("/var/www/transactions.csv", "r+") as f:
    olddata = f.read()
    f.seek(0)
    c = csv.writer(f);
    c.writerow([addre, oldamount, "win"])
    f.write(olddata)
```

Note that this can corrupt your file if something goes wrong while writing. If you want to minimize that possibility, write to a new file, then `os.rename()` it to overwrite the old one.

Comment: NameError: global name 'file_f' is not defined

Comment: Sorry, copy'n'paste error. Updated my answer. If you still need to recalculate ``oldamount``, do it before the with block, to keep the amount of code under the 'with' block as small as possible.

Comment: That's great. How would I go about rewriting only the first 20 lines (or deleting the last line before I re-write)

Comment: Read the data using a CSV reader, modify the data, write out the new data. If there is a possibility of 2 processes updating the file at the same time, look into file locking mechanisms.